# ngResource setting const string after param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, ngresource

I'm trying to create a url that will query as:

```
http://localhost/api/:videoID/subtitles
```

However writing this in angularjs using ngResource transform it into a different "format":

```
$resource("api/videos/:id", {id: "@_id"}, {
    getTracks:  {method: "GET", url: "api/video/:video_id/tracks", params: {video_id: "@_id"}}
});
//results into: http://localhost/api/subtitles?videoID=:videoID
```

Does anyone know how to fix this exactly?

Comment: is that a correct answer thought?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hkm6tdwo/ I tried to test it but im struggeling with angularjs atm. Sorry for not answering this sooner, I've been busy with school.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the route mask to following:

```
$resource("api/:id/subtitles", {id: "@id"});
```